# kivy KeyError in an ids dictionary

Tags: kivy

I have the following code snippet:

```
def on_articles(self, *args):

        #self.parent.ids['recommendations'].update_recommendations(self.articles)
        self.parent.children[0].update_recommendations(self.articles)
```

The commented line does not work, because `self.parent.ids` is an empty dictionary (`{}`)
The uncommented line does work. Why? How to best refer to Recommendations widget?

Here is the UI.

```
Builder.load_string('''
<SearchItem>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1] if self.state == 'normal' else [30/255, 139/255, 195/255, 1]
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

    color: 0, 0, 0, 1

<Urlpopup>:
    size_hint: .7, .7
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: ''

    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: self.width * 0.1
        spacing: self.height * 0.1


        Spinner:
            id: spinner
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            text: 'en'
            values: 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'it'

        SearchBar:
            id: searchbar
            size_hint: 1, 0.4
            multiline: False
            font_size: self.height*0.8

        Recommendations:
            id: recommendations
            orientation: 'vertical'
            SearchItem
''')
```

Comment: Add a `print(self.parent)` to your `on_articles()` method. If the printed parent is not a `Urlpopup`, then you are trying to access the `ids` of the wrong widget.

Comment: @JohnAnderson parent is BoxLayout. It should be clear, because the uncommented line works as expected.

Comment: The `ids` are not in the `BoxLayout`, they are in the `Urlpopup`. They are always in the root object of the `kv` rule where they are defined.

Comment: @JohnAnderson When I call `self.parent.parent.ids['recommendations'].update_recommendations(self.articles) it ends with `KeyError` as well.

Comment: If you `print(self.parent.parent)`, does it show `Urlpopup`?

Comment: It shows the BoxLayout.

Comment: Then the `ids` will not work. The `ids` are in the `Urlpopup`, if you try to access the `ids` in any other widget, you will get that error.